# Use docker-compose with port mapping for local Kafka testing

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I'm trying to get the infrastructure for a black box service test up and running using `docker-compose`. I want to do that on Jenkins, for multiple services, therefore it is necessary to bind to build-specific port (e.g. 50012 instead of 9092) for the build should be able to run in parallel.

The problem is, that producing messages fails.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
---
version: "3.4"

services:

  zookeeper:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest"
    ports:
      - "2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"

  kafka:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_PROTOCOL_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PROTOCOL_NAME: OUTSIDE
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: "OUTSIDE://localhost:50012,INSIDE://kafka:9092"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "OUTSIDE://localhost:50012,INSIDE://kafka:9092"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
    ports:
      - "50012:9092"
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

I don't see any errors but this one (which I think can be ignored):

```
ERROR Could not submit metrics to Kafka topic __confluent.support.metrics: Failed to construct kafka producer (io.confluent.support.metrics.BaseMetricsReporter)
```

When I try to send a message with Kafka console producer like this

```
echo 'my-message' | kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:50012 --topic test
```

I get this exception and the message does not get sent:

```
[2018-07-25 10:56:31,283] ERROR Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value: 10 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
```

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.

---

UPDATE:
Thanks to the correct answer from Robin, we were able to get it running with following docker-compose.yml:

```
---
version: "3.4"

services:

zookeeper:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest"
    environment:
    ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
    ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"

kafka:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest"
    environment:
    KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
    KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: "INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT"
    KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: "INSIDE"
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "INSIDE://kafka:29092,OUTSIDE://localhost:50012"
    KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
    ports:
      - "50012:50012"
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

Comment: Have a look at this [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/Paizo/iotStreams/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) it uses wurstmeister's image but the point is the use of `hostname` to properly handle the the listeners

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it did not work either. However, I updated the question for it carries a little further I guess.
A key difference between your use case and mine is that I need to contact Kafka from *outside* the docker-compose default network. So I need that KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS stuff.

Comment: it is reachable from outside with that as well if you add that hostname to the hostfile as well

Comment: @Paizo, I'm not sure what you mean with "add that hostname to the hostfile", but I think I don't want to do that. My idea is to run several Kafka instances on a generic Jenkins. I wound like to avoid changing the Jenkins system.

Comment: are your containers running on windows?  I've experienced a similar issue on windows because windows can't route 'localhost' to the docker container IP.  I had to manually find the IP (which turned out to be Default Switch) used by docker and use that instead of localhost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your config is

```
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "OUTSIDE://localhost:50012,INSIDE://kafka:9092"
[…]
    ports:
      - "50012:9092"
```

The `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` is exactly that - the address that the broker advertises. So on one hand you're configuring it as `localhost:50012`, but then on the other you're exposing from your Docker config `9092` as the external port.

If you simply use

```
 ports:
      - "50012:50012"
```

then it should work fine.

Check out this [docker-compose](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/mysql-debezium-ksql-elasticsearch/docker-compose/docker-compose.yml) for an example of a working config that exposes Kafka externally and internally.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm experimenting keeping your advise in mind, but up to now it did not work. I found a solution that seems to work using the `50012:9092" mapping, tough. I'll post it as an answer today, but I still don't understand why it works and I'm not too happy with it.

Comment: "it did not work" is not descriptive :) If you can detail in what way it didn't work, I can help out further.

Comment: Yes, I know that "it did not work" was kind of a bad description, sorry for that. Actually you were right, but we had to change more than just the port mapping. I'll add the full working docker-compose.yml. Thanks a lot, @Robin.

Comment: Final question: it only seems to work with port `29092` instead of `9092`. What is that port?

Comment: There's no reason why `9092` shouldn't work. I suggest you open a new question detailing in what way it doesn't work ;) From the docker-compose you've posted in your updated question, it looks fine. All other containers on that docker network would access the broker on `kafka:29092` as currently configured.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I cannot stress enough how much I thank you for this answer.
It was not clear to me how kafka is working internally and I owe you a big time for this.